# what is the significance of the "com" prefix in a bundle id?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I always find myself confused when using itunes connect.  I understand bundleid is some kind of identifier for my app.  but what is the purpose of the "com" prefix if everyone uses that?  That doesn't make your bundle id any more unique?

does it matter if my bundle id is:

mycompany.app
**vs**
com.mycompany.app

I know this has been asked a lot, but I still find myself really confused by the whole process.

Comment: You can give whatever name you need as your bundle Id. But the most preferred is reverse domain notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a convention that Apple recommends for uniqueness. Since Internet domain names are guaranteed to be unique, using them in your bundle id ensures it's unique.

Two companies might have the same name, for example Acme, but only one of them could own the domain name acme.com. The other company would have a different domain name, such as acme.biz. This would result in each having unique bundle ids.

Comment: so there are people with org, and net bundle ids?  
if i mistakenly leave off the com off my bundle id on one app vs another will that cause me any problems?

Comment: Yes, if they are using reverse domain names. If you made a mistake, it might cause problems later or it might not.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

Answer (score 2):

Putting the domain extension at the beginning of the name is known as [Reverse Domain Name Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_domain_name_notation). In practice it is beneficial because it provides a very specific namespace. If two companies have the same name, only one of them can own the corresponding .com domain for that name, and thus you avoid conflicts that might arise otherwise.

Comment: If they both use com as a prefix how does that make the domain any more unique?

Comment: Only one company can own the corresponding .com of the companies name.